# Using WCF service for windows mobile and server communication?

Tags: json, wcf, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I am using [this code for Windows phone and server communication using WCF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/how-to-consume-wcf-rest-service-returning-json-in-windows-ph/) for sending my data from phone to server and get response. But I am getting error "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

How this URI is created:

```
string ServiceUri = "http://localhost:30576/Service1.svc/Rest/add/"
                    + Number1 + "/" + Number2;
```

I did not understand from where `/Rest/add/` came from. I may be getting error due to this.

Comment: Did you try without "Rest" ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the web.config, at the "RESTEndPoint" section. His base address for the endpoint is "rest". So you have to use what ever is there in your web.config endpoint address.